# How to push CSS shape at the bottom out of the screen?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to replicate this mockup.

[image: Mockup]

And I successfully pushed that top circular shap out of the screen like in the picture. But the bottom one is just lengthening the webpage without going out of the screen. How to push it out of the screen like in the picture?

```
#circleTop {
    width: 55rem;
    height: 55rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, red, yellow);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 60%;
    top: -35rem;
}

#circleBottom {
    width: 50rem;
    height: 50rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, green, blue);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    right: 45%;
    bottom: -35rem;
}

<div class="header">
            <div id="circleTop"></div>
            <div class="headerBox">
                <h1>Headline</h1>
                <h2>Subheading</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
 ....

<div class="footer">
           <div id="circleBottom"></div>
            <div class="section">
                <a href="#">Link</a>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </div>
            <div class="otherLinks">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Did you try by using position: absolute?

Comment: I think you may want to re-frame the issue as: how can I prevent my main window from expanding to fill all content? The answer is: restrict the size of your main window.

Comment: @AbelValdez I did.

Comment: I did a comment below

Comment: @afarley hmm I don't want to restrict the middle container (it can grow as long as it wants), but the header and footer can stay fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The answers so far aren't wrong, but IMO they are incomplete. If you want to have your circle be 'cut off' and not become visible when you scroll down, it will need to be contained in another element that will restrict its visibility.  `position:absolute;` is part of the solution, but it will position your element in relation to the nearest containing element that has a position defined - so your footer div will likely need `position:relative;` added.  Then, you'll need to make sure the part of the circle that's supposed to be cut of isn't visible even though it overflows the bottom of the footer, so adding `overflow:hidden` will finish the job.  This should get you headed in the right direction:

```
.footer {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

you may or may not actually want that to be applied to the footer div, but the principle is the same...overflowing elements will be visible and cause scrolling unless you tell them not to, so having it overflow the page is really an illusion created by having another element 'crop' or hide the part that would be overflowing.  As some other answers have suggested, you could do that by styling the body or html elements, but the behavior is usually more predictable if you use an element nearer to the one you want to be cut off.  For example setting a fixed height or 'overflow:hidden;' on the body would prevent your page from scrolling if you add content that is taller than the screen.

Comment: Hi! There is a small problem. The footer already had a relative position and adding overflow:hidden clipped the bottom part of the circle nicely, but clipped the top part as well.

Comment: You may need to adjust the size and position (top/left values) of the circle, as well as the size of the footer to achieve your exact effect - hopefully the concept I’ve described gives you the info you need to experiment and customize as needed,

Answer (score 1):

You add element body and css as below:

```css
body{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#circleTop {
    width: 55rem;
    height: 55rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, red, yellow);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    right: -25rem;
    top: -25rem;
}

#circleBottom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 55rem;
    height: 55rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, green, blue);
    border-radius: 50%; 
    z-index: -1;
    left: -25rem;
    bottom: -25rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div id="circleTop"></div>
    <div class="headerBox">
      <h1>Headline</h1>
      <h2>Subheading</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div id="circleBottom"></div>
    <div class="section">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="otherLinks">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it would be good to explain the purpose/effect of adding `height:100vh` on the body.  I think that makes some big assumptions about the itent of the mock up and would lead to some display problems when the page is viewed on different sized screens...for instance on a tablet vs a laptop.  You're on the right track, but without clarifying what your snippet is doing, it's quite possible it could create a bigger challenge for the OP than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the follow class for bottm left circle

```
#circleBottom {
    width: 50rem;
    height: 50rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, green, blue);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: -15%;
    bottom: -15%;
}
```

[Circle example](http://tpcg.io/aknJLq)

Comment: Yes I just tried it. Unfortuantely didn't solve it. Adding overflow:hidden to the footer solves the problem partially. It does cut the bootom but also the top.